# MSSQL - String Concatenation for a Default

Tags: sql-server

This question is two parts:

1. How would I set a default constraint so that a column defaults to a concatenation of columns within the same table?

Here was my attempt:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[LANDGRID_PLSS_SECTIONS]
ADD CONSTRAINT DF_GIS_SECTION_ID DEFAULT 
    (SELECT CONCAT(MERIDIAN_CODE,ST_CODE,CNTY_CODE,TOWNSHIP_NUM,TOWNSHIP_DIR,RANGE_NUM,RANGE_DIR,SECT) FROM [dbo].[LANDGRID_PLSS_SECTIONS] )
FOR GIS_SECTION_ID
```

2. Would this column then be available to use as a foreign key? If not, is their a way to so something similar?

Comment: Using concatenation like this is a *BAD* idea because it breaks even the 1st normal form. 1 field, 1 value.

Comment: I think you want to look at computed columns. But what you posted seems pretty brittle to me. It would just create a long list of characters which could allow for collisions. You probably want to add a delimiter, or better yet, find something better than 10 or so columns crammed together like that.

Comment: *Instead* of concatenating values, make sure the `LANDGRID_PLSS_SECTIONS` table has a proper primary key (single field) and add a reference to *that*

Comment: Do you want this column to ALWAYS contain the concatenated values of the other columns?   Or do you need to be able to override this value with INSERT/UPDATE?   If the former, then you want a computed column instead of a default constraint.

Comment: @TabAlleman if you google for PLSS LandGrid you'll find that this is an entire GIS entry's worth of data. Copying that data from the reference table like this is a very bad idea. What if a *non-key* attribute changes?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13683413/referencing-another-column-in-default-definition-in-sql-server-2005

Comment: I understand this is not ideal, I am having to do this because the tables, while in the same database, are "governed" by separate  systems.  I am wondering if a second cross reference table may be the answer. One that keeps track of the pk and the concatenation i need. I need the concatenation because I have one system that uses that as a key. Certainly open to other solutions.

Comment: I thought maybe a bound default, but no. there is NO WAY to reference another column in a default constraint.  The above referenced question is your duplicate.

Comment: I think the referenced question above may actually solve it. Would that then allow for me to build a relationship off of it? And would manipulating the insert statement have any negative side effects?

Comment: Yes, it would just be a regular column that got populated by the trigger at insert/update time.  What do you mean by "manipulating the insert statement"?

Comment: Well this could be my lack of experience showing... But the solution suggests that it will use the trigger instead of the insert/update statement... So my question would be if doing so would effect anything else related to the table and/or stored procedures pointing to the table etc...